# Unable to debug a program that uses concurrent async / await

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, .net-4.5, async-await

**Observations [on this program](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Async-Sample-Example-from-9b9f505c):**

- Pressing F11 slowly through this program doesn't show every execution of `ProcessURL()`
- Pressing F11 quickly through this program shows more executions of `ProcessURL()`
- Using `Thread.Sleep(3000);` in ProcessURL results in the MainUI thread hanging for approximately 30 seconds.  No UI Redraws, and the cancel button is unavailable.

**Needs:**

- I want to step through every execution of ProcessURL, or perhaps visualize it like this using native Visual Studio tooling or open source add ins

[image]

**Code**

[Download available here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Async-Sample-Example-from-9b9f505c)

```
namespace ProcessTasksAsTheyFinish
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        // Declare a System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource.
        CancellationTokenSource cts;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void startButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            resultsTextBox.Clear();

            // Instantiate the CancellationTokenSource.
            cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

            try
            {
                await AccessTheWebAsync(cts.Token);
                resultsTextBox.Text += "\r\nDownloads complete.";
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                resultsTextBox.Text += "\r\nDownloads canceled.\r\n";
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                resultsTextBox.Text += "\r\nDownloads failed.\r\n";
            }

            cts = null;
        }


        private void cancelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (cts != null)
            {
                cts.Cancel();
            }
        }


        async Task AccessTheWebAsync(CancellationToken ct)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            // Make a list of web addresses.
            List<string> urlList = SetUpURLList();

            // ***Create a query that, when executed, returns a collection of tasks.
            IEnumerable<Task<int>> downloadTasksQuery =
                from url in urlList select ProcessURL(url, client, ct);

            // ***Use ToList to execute the query and start the tasks. 
            List<Task<int>> downloadTasks = downloadTasksQuery.ToList();

            // ***Add a loop to process the tasks one at a time until none remain.
            while (downloadTasks.Count > 0)
            {
                    // Identify the first task that completes.
                    Task<int> firstFinishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(downloadTasks);

                    // ***Remove the selected task from the list so that you don't
                    // process it more than once.
                    downloadTasks.Remove(firstFinishedTask);

                    // Await the completed task.
                    int length = await firstFinishedTask;
                    resultsTextBox.Text += String.Format
                        ("\r\nLength of the download:  {0}", length);
            }
        }


        private List<string> SetUpURLList()
        {
            List<string> urls = new List<string> 
            { 
                "http://msdn.microsoft.com",
                "http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br211380.aspx",
                "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh290136.aspx",
                "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470362.aspx",
                "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578028.aspx",
                "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404677.aspx",
                "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730837.aspx"
            };
            return urls;
        }


        async Task<int> ProcessURL(string url, HttpClient client, CancellationToken ct)
        {
            // GetAsync returns a Task<HttpResponseMessage>. 
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url, ct);
            // Retrieve the website contents from the HttpResponseMessage.
            byte[] urlContents = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

            return urlContents.Length;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: VS.NET 2012 *does* allow you to step through everything even through `async`/`await` scenarios.  That said, where did you place the call to `Thread.Sleep`?

Comment: @casperOne I just pressed F11 now and stepped through every line. ProcessURL() only is called once with the first URL (according to the debugger).  I placed Thread.Sleep in ProcessURL and the main window thread locked up.

Comment: Are you looking for a visualization tool, or to understand what's going on?  The first type of question is not constructive (tool lists, shopping recommendations are not a good fit for the site); the second question is answerable and more of a fit for the site.

Comment: @casperOne I want to understand what is going on.  I'm not shopping and am grasping at straws to trace or visualize the concurrency.  I remember hearing on Channel 9 that this visualization was available in the debugger, but now I need it I can't find it.

Comment: @makerofthings7: Is that "locked up permanently" or "froze the UI for a few seconds"?

Comment: @JonSkeet I just re-ran it with a 3 second sleep.  The cancel button could not be pressed, the UI would not redraw itself ... for approx 30 seconds after pressing the start button.

Comment: @makerofthings7: Well that makes sense. You've blocked the UI thread for 7 * 3 seconds...

Comment: @JonSkeet ;) Yes I got that far, but I did that to slow down the concurrency so I can F11 through it.  I'm looking for a better approach to learn and demonstrate concurrency.  I could Console.Writeline each execution, but prefer something better that I can reuse in future projects.

Comment: @makerofthings7: What *exact* method are you trying to step into with F11 though? That's the thing that confuses me.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you put the call to `Thread.Sleep` *before* the `await` call, it makes perfect sense that the UI thread locked up: you were blocking it. Your `ProcessURL` method will execute synchronously until you hit the first `await` expression for something that hasn't completed. When it gets there, it will attach a continuation and then return.

So if you had the `Thread.Sleep` call before the await, when your LINQ query is executed (when you call `ToList`, you'll call that method 7 times in a row, sleeping in the UI thread for 3 seconds each time. The UI will be locked up while that happens. If you put `Thread.Sleep` *after* the `await`, then the UI will still be locked up for the same amount of time, but in small bursts.

The asynchronous equivalent of `Thread.Sleep` is to use [`Task.Delay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.delay.aspx):

```
await Task.Delay(3000);
```

This will basically return immediately, attaching a continuation which will fire in 3 seconds.

(I don't know about the debugging issues - I wouldn't be trying to debug *into* most of those statements... it's not clear to me exactly what you were trying to achieve or why. A breakpoint in `ProcessURL` should get hit for each URL though.)

Comment: I placed Thread.Sleep right before return `urlContents.Length()` in `ProcessURL()`.  I replaced this line with `await Task.Delay(10000)` (10 seconds) and saw the text "Downloads Complete" within 14 seconds.  This helps me slow down execution.  Is there a better way to debug similar situations in the future?

Comment: The reason I want to debug is so I can add a Watch statement on one of my iterations.  Assume I have a logic error in `ProcessURL()` I'm looking for a technique to figure that out. If await `Task(`) with `Console.Writeline()` is my only way... so be it.

Comment: @makerofthings7: Why not just add a breakpoint? That should be fine. (As for a way to figure out logic errors - that's what unit tests are for, of course :)